# How can I evaluate if my input argument has all even bits set to 1?

Tags: c, logic, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to do bit logic manipulation in C but getting stuck. I need to write a function that, given an input argument it will evaluate if my argument has all even bits set to 1. For example:

```
myFunction (0xFFFFFFFE) = 0;
myFunction (0x55555555) = 1;
```

The operators that I'm permitted to use are: `!` `~` `&` `^` `|` `+` `<<` `>>`. I can't use `if` statements, loops, or equality checks (so no `==` or `!=` operators).

Comment: Hint: Try &'ing with a mask.

Comment: How would you tell if bit 0 is set?  How about bit 2?  Then how would you test both at the same time?  Etc...

Comment: Too many permitted operations.

Comment: @Jack maybe reducing the permitted operations set would give too much of a hint...

Comment: And maybe reducing the permitted operations wouldn't have led to this question in the first place :)

Comment: Too localized. It doesn't make any sense whatsoever to say "I can't use these common features of the language".

Comment: What would be more difficult while `!` is permitted but not permit `!=`?

Answer (score 6):

You need to test the value with a mask, and be a little bit devious about how you test for equality without using `==`, e.g.:

```
return !((n & 0x55555555) ^ 0x55555555);
```

NB: this assumes a 32 bit value.

Comment: do we need the `== 0x55555555`?

Comment: @Aniket: yes, this is why your solution does not work.

Comment: `==` isn't allowed though, right?  But you could replace with `+` and a `!`, I think.

Comment: Or just cheat it with `~` and `!`.

Comment: ah, I see where I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, fixed the `==` with a `!` and a `^` now.

Comment: Isn't is `0xaaaaaaaa`? Perhaps my brain is just sleeping.

Comment: @Jack, those are the odd-numbered bits.  The lowest bit is bit 0.

Comment: @CarlNorum Oh, I call the LSB bit #1 ;-)

Comment: @Jack Real programmers index from zero. :P

Comment: Okay, but that's not the normal way to go about it.  It represents the 2^0 place, after all.

Comment: To mix boolean and bitwise operators in general, is considered sloppy and poor style.

Comment: We got a winner!! Thank you so much!!! :)

Answer (score 4):

As '==' is not permitted, one must use other tricks:

```
 (~number & 0x55555555) will be zero only when number&mask == mask.
 (~number & 0x55555555)==0 OTOH codes as 

 return !(~number & 0x55555555);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you solve it using C programming, without any weird artificial limits placed upon yourself:

```
// Get a platform-independent mask of all even bits in an int set to one:
#define MASK ( (unsigned int) 0x55555555u )

// MASK will be 0x5555u or 0x55555555u depending on sizeof(int).
```

And then the actual algorithm:

```
if((x & MASK) == MASK)
```

Comment: As you can hopefully tell, the last line is so much more readable than any bitwise-operator madness you would be forced to use, if you placed artificial limits on which language features you can't use. Consider focusing on learning C programming, and not on obfuscating your code to an unreadable mess because some incompetent teacher says so. That will _not_ make you a better programmer.